# filter doesn't work properly when hiding specific column of a table on input uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to hide specific columns of a table when unchecking the checkbox and its working perfectly but the problem is i am using "dataTable" and it has filter to show records like 10 record or 25 or 50 and so on. let say i did hide a column "Age" by unchecking it and its worked perfectly but as you can see there is a show record filter as well and when i select to show records 25 or 50 or etc.., hidden column items visibles after the records 10, i have wasted lots of time on it but couldn't make it correct. can anyone help me with that??? below is the codes please check

LET ME GUIDE YOU TO ANALYSE THE PROBLEM: 
 
 1. Unchecked any of the column like : "Age".
 2. Now select records 10 to 25 or 50 you will see the problem in the table below.

```js
            


                    function filterGlobal() {
                        $('#example').DataTable().search(
                            $('#global_filter').val(),
                            $('#global_regex').prop('checked'),
                            $('#global_smart').prop('checked')
                        ).draw();
                    }

                    function filterColumn(i) {
                        $('#example').DataTable().column(i).search(
                            $('#col' + i + '_filter').val(),
                            $('#col' + i + '_regex').prop('checked'),
                            $('#col' + i + '_smart').prop('checked')
                        ).draw();
                    }

                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#example').DataTable();

                        $('input.global_filter').on('keyup click', function () {
                            filterGlobal();
                        });

                        $('input.column_filter').on('keyup click', function () {
                            filterColumn($(this).parents('tr').attr('data-column'));
                        });
                    });
                
                    $(".nametoggleCheck").click(function () {
                        $('.dataTableShow td:nth-child(1),.dataTableShow th:nth-child(1)').stop().toggle();
                    })
                    $(".positiontoggleCheck").click(function () {
                        $('.dataTableShow td:nth-child(1),.dataTableShow th:nth-child(1)').stop().toggle();
                    })
                    $(".officetoggleCheck").click(function () {
                        $('.dataTableShow td:nth-child(1),.dataTableShow th:nth-child(1)').stop().toggle();
                    })
                    $(".agetoggleCheck").click(function () {
                        $('.dataTableShow td:nth-child(1),.dataTableShow th:nth-child(1)').stop().toggle();
                    })
                    $(".starttoggleCheck").click(function () {
                        $('.dataTableShow td:nth-child(1),.dataTableShow th:nth-child(1)').stop().toggle();
                    })
                    $(".salarytoggleCheck").click(function () {
                        $('.dataTableShow td:nth-child(1),.dataTableShow th:nth-child(1)').stop().toggle();
                    })
```

```html
<!-- input box to hide column when unchecked -->
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input class="nametoggleCheck" type="checkbox" checked> Name</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="positiontoggleCheck" checked> Pisition</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="officetoggleCheck" checked> Office</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="agetoggleCheck" checked> Age</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="starttoggleCheck" checked> Start date</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="salarytoggleCheck" checked> Salary</li>
                </ul>
                <!-- input box to hide column when unchecked end -->


<!-- table where specific column will get hide -->
                <table id="example" class="display dataTableShow" border="1" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Position</th>
                            <th>Office</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Start date</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- table where specific column will get hide -->
<!--=== SCRIPT ======-->
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
      </script>
<!-- data table js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because you are using a custom hiding method, and it selects only the currently visible items without interacting with the datatable itself.

You should follow the datatable API like in their docs: https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

I added a global var to keep the datatable object, you can move elsewhere, it was simpler for the example to set it global:

```js
            

                    //var for the datatable object
                    var globDataTable;

                    function filterGlobal() {
                        $('#example').DataTable().search(
                            $('#global_filter').val(),
                            $('#global_regex').prop('checked'),
                            $('#global_smart').prop('checked')
                        ).draw();
                    }

                    function filterColumn(i) {
                        $('#example').DataTable().column(i).search(
                            $('#col' + i + '_filter').val(),
                            $('#col' + i + '_regex').prop('checked'),
                            $('#col' + i + '_smart').prop('checked')
                        ).draw();
                    }

                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        //store the datatable object
                        globDataTable = $('#example').DataTable();

                        $('input.global_filter').on('keyup click', function () {
                            filterGlobal();
                        });

                        $('input.column_filter').on('keyup click', function () {
                            filterColumn($(this).parents('tr').attr('data-column'));
                        });
                    });
                
                    $(".nametoggleCheck").click(function () {
                        //get column
                        var col = globDataTable.column(0);
                        //toggle visibility
                        col.visible( !col.visible() );
                    })
                    $(".positiontoggleCheck").click(function () {
                        //get column
                        var col = globDataTable.column(1);
                        //toggle visibility
                        col.visible( !col.visible() );
                    })
                    $(".officetoggleCheck").click(function () {
                        //get column
                        var col = globDataTable.column(2);
                        //toggle visibility
                        col.visible( !col.visible() );
                    })
                    $(".agetoggleCheck").click(function () {
                        //get column
                        var col = globDataTable.column(3);
                        //toggle visibility
                        col.visible( !col.visible() );
                    })
                    $(".starttoggleCheck").click(function () {
                        //get column
                        var col = globDataTable.column(4);
                        //toggle visibility
                        col.visible( !col.visible() );
                    })
                    $(".salarytoggleCheck").click(function () {
                        //get column
                        var col = globDataTable.column(5);
                        //toggle visibility
                        col.visible( !col.visible() );
                    })
```

```html
<!-- input box to hide column when unchecked -->
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input class="nametoggleCheck" type="checkbox" checked> Name</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="positiontoggleCheck" checked> Pisition</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="officetoggleCheck" checked> Office</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="agetoggleCheck" checked> Age</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="starttoggleCheck" checked> Start date</li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="salarytoggleCheck" checked> Salary</li>
                </ul>
                <!-- input box to hide column when unchecked end -->


<!-- table where specific column will get hide -->
                <table id="example" class="display dataTableShow" border="1" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Position</th>
                            <th>Office</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Start date</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- table where specific column will get hide -->
<!--=== SCRIPT ======-->
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
      </script>
<!-- data table js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: still not working, i visited to the site you have mentioned above but i didn't understand anything there.. can you please make it work for me???